# Git Repo for Doom Config With Different Platforms

Tags: git, config, doom

I have emacs on two separate platforms, and I would like it to function in much the same way on both, but there is some platform-dependent configuration as well. I have created a git repository in my .doom.d directory (where the doom configuration files are stored). I could have two branches, one for each platform, but then I end up re-implementing much of my config. I found this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200068/applying-commits-into-another-branch-without-merging.
I would like to know if there is a better way (I am pretty new to git), preferably simpler. Is there something like a C preprocessor directive I could use where certain portions of my config are ommitted before they are evaluated based on the platform I am on? Is there something else that I don't know about? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.  One way is to put system dependent stuff in a file `machine.el` where "machine" is what `(system-name)` outputs.  I then put

```
(require (intern (system-name)) nil 'noerror)
```

in my `init.el` and keep everything in the same GitHub repo.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I tried putting that in `$DOOMDIR/init.el` (running `doom build && doom sync`) as well as `$DOOMDIR/config.el` and neither seemed to work. Currently, the only thing I have in my `$DOOMDIR/machine.el` (where `machine` is replaced by the output of `(system-name)`) is `(setq org-directory "~/../../org/")


(setq doom-variable-pitch-font (font-spec :family "Times New Roman" :size 12))` and when I do `C-h v org-directory` or `C-h v doom-variable-pitch-font` it says the value is nil. Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Inspect the variable `load-path`.  Does it contain $DOOMDIR?

Comment: No. Should I put `machine.el` elsewhere?

Comment: I moved `machine.el` and added its location to `load-path`. It works now.